# Jenkins is adding private regisrty URL tag while pulling Image

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting this issue in Jenkins pipeline where I want to pull 'node' image but jenkins is adding the private docker registry url tag to it so the image is not found (artifactory.x.com/node:7-alpine)

Here is the pipeline

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker
    {
        image 'node:7-alpine'
        registryUrl 'https://artifactory.x.com/'
        registryCredentialsId 'jenkins-artifactory'

    }
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'node --version'
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the error I am getting

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/jobs/enterprise-master/workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
$ docker login -u jenkins -p ******** https://artifactory.x.com/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /var/jenkins_home/jobs/enterprise-master/workspace@tmp/f54c8b21-837b-4652-b12c-d489fb7e4c4c/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . node:7-alpine

Error: No such object: node:7-alpine
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . artifactory.x.com/node:7-alpine

Error: No such object: artifactory.x.com/node:7-alpine
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull artifactory.x.com/node:7-alpine
Error response from daemon: unknown: Not Found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
```

Now the problem is that there is no image artifactory.x.com/node:7-alpine so it cant be found.

How do I tell jenkins not to add the private repo URL while pulling.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing Docker Registry URL and setting Registry credentials to none

```
Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins->Configure > Pipeline Model Definition
```

Also the pipeline definition is still same

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker
        {
            image 'node:7-alpine'
            registryUrl 'https://artifactory.X.com/'
            registryCredentialsId 'jenkins-artifactory'

        }
```